# Compile error in ruby on rails application (error is with rails form helpers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm writing a ruby on rails application, and am getting a compile error for the following code

```
<%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get") do %>
<%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

this is sample code from the ruby on rails forms guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

The error generated is,

compile error
/Users/kmb89144/Desktop/Stoastic/app/views/application/index.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected ')'
...h_path, :method => "get") do ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat ...
                              ^
/Users/kmb89144/Desktop/Stoastic/app/views/application/index.html.erb:13: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting ')'
/Users/kmb89144/Desktop/Stoastic/app/views/application/index.html.erb:15: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting ')'

Extracted source (around line #3):

```
1:
```

2:

3:   <%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get") do %>

4:     <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>

5:     <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>

6:     <%= submit_tag("Search") %>

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Rails do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove `=` from form line:

```
<% form_tag(search_path, :method => "get") do %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `form_with`, because in the new versions of Rails 5 the functions `form_for` and `form_tag` will be discontinued.

Use that:

```
<%= form_with(url: search_path, method: :get, local:true) do |f|%>
  <%= f.label 'Search for:' %>
  <%= f.text_field :q, id: :q %>
  <%= f.submit 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

References:
https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a